# Docker "Something Went Wrong" when starting

Tags: docker

After installing Docker Desktop on Windows 11, it works fine for a couple of sessions but after a couple of days it shows this error when starting:

> Something went wrong
>
> Creating "rootNode" subnodes: constructing "BackendServices" in
> "rootNode": doing migrations: migrating settings.json: type mismatch
> for key wslEngineEnabled - missing a migration step : string != bool

I have WSL enabled in the Resources/WSL integration settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by modifying `C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Docker/settings.json`

For some reason, it autofills the key `"wslEngineEnabled": "false"`. Not only was it set to false, but also wrote as a string instead of bool. As I said, this happened by default, without me having even opened the file.

Fixed it to `"wslEngineEnabled": true`

Answer (score 4):

Delete seettings file /AppData/Roaming/Docker/settings.json and start docker with admin privileges

[image: Docker "Something Went Wrong" when starting]

Comment: The other solution does not require to start it with admin privileges